# Open anyway for not verified app not working despite being unlocked

Tags: macos, security

Open anyway for not verified app not working despite being unlocked. Any help is much appreciated
[image]

Comment: Perhaps we could hone this title [& maybe Q body too] - because what the OP has is an audio plugin that cannot be launched on its own. It can only be launched as a daughter process of an audio app. This is going to make it tricky to work around. [Personally, I'm a bit out of practise with VSTs & how they interact with the modern OS]

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the app in Finder and control click (right click) on the icon and select open?

Sometimes that brings up the approval prompt more readily for me (in fact, I’ve never once used the interface you show above).

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

This second step is documented in the official apple help as the next step after you select Open Anyway.

[image]

> The app is now saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it, just as you can any authorized app.

Comment: I've only seen the OP's issue when a faceless app was opened either at boot or by another process. idk that particular plugin, but a .vst is an audio plugin for Cubase etc, so is going to be launched as the parent app loads & cannot be launched on its own. Not sure how to get around it not working when told to open anyway, short of checking for an update.